# Dynamically remove all content between between script tags of a html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose, in my project homepage there are some javascript code. For example,

**index.html**

```
    <body>
    html code here

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {

    some javascript code here

      })();
    </script>


 <button type="button">Delete javascript</button> 
    </body>
```

Now, what I want is that, on clicking on the button all content between script tags should be deleted along with script tags.  How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know that removing a script tag doesn't affect execution of it's codes? Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: `document.body.removeChild(yourScriptElem);`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try putting an ID or Class on your script tag and then onlick find that ID or Class and remove it? Something like:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#script-tag-id').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  alert(document.body.innerHTML)
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('yourScript')){
      var script = document.getElementById('yourScript');
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
    alert(document.body.innerHTML);
  };
});
```

```html
<body>
  html code here
  <script id="yourScript" type="text/javascript">
    /*testing*/
  </script>
  <button id="button" type="button">Delete javascript</button>
</body>
```